# How to put the outcome of a javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am running a function which is translates some slang/ abbreviation phrases to real English words. 
    function word () {
    var text= document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
    for (var i=0; i

```
}
</script>
</body>
</H2>
</HTML>
```

As you can probably see, I have a CSS style sheet attached. I will posts this is as well in case it helps anyone solve my problem!

```
/* CSS Document */
body {
 background-color: #616161;
 font-size: 20px;
color: WHITE;
font-family:"Goudy Stout"; 
 }
h2 {
font size: 11px;
color: balck;
font-family: Calibri;
}
```

Comment: And now it doesn't seem to be working at all! I would be grateful if anyone can point out what has gone wrong?

Comment: If you broke something, just backtrack your steps.  Do you have a JSFIDDLE we can use to tinker?

Comment: I'm not sure what a JSfiddle is?

Comment: Its a website where you can create sharable code for us to tinker.  Has a HTML, CSS, JS, and [output] section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace the alert with this line:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('textbox')[1].value=text

// 1. You need to get the <input class=textbox>
// document.getElementsByClassName('textbox')

// 2. This will return an array, you need the second Element [2]
// .value=text
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I worked out what was wrong with the version I posted compared to older versions I changed them first, and then tried your solution! One big mistake I made was "gii" rather than "gi" and using "text" rather than "test" in many places, and vice versa. You have saved me a lot of time, although I've spent a while already trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Replace alert with this code

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("textbox");
elems[1].value = text;
```

There is another simple way to do this. Assign an Id to the textbox and write this line

```
<input type= "text" class="textbox" value= "Translation should appear here"></input>

var elem = document.getElementById("textbox");
elem.value = text;
```

Hope this works.

Comment: looks like it works great thank you, but I'll stick with the other solution, just because it was first! If other people look at this, this one works perfectly fine as well!